# How do I restore my Multibit wallet without seed words?

Tags: multibit

So I created my BTC wallet back in 2013 and had always kept a backup of the files handy. The computer I used has since died and now that I've installed the latest version of Multibit on my new computer, I can't figure out how to restore my wallet. It asks me for seed words, but I do not recall ever having seed words when the wallet was created.

I have the files multibit.info, multibit.wallet, and wallet.aes.json among other backups (along with my password). How do I get to a point where I can get my wallet up and running again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2013, MultiBit was not using Hierachal Deterministic (HD) wallets. The latest version is MultiBit HD. If you want to use the older version you can use [MultiBit Classic](https://multibit.org/releases/multibit-classic/multibit-classic-0.5.19/) and that should let you import your `multibit.wallet` file.

Answer (score -1):

Take your private keys you had with Multibit, go make a new wallet on the blockchain.com site and restore your wallet there

Comment: Please elaborate on the steps involved in doing so. This could in general help others who would have faced similar problems.

Comment: You should not store more in an online wallet than you can afford to lose. If the online wallet provider goes offline, goes broke, is hacked, is shut down or, if they just steal your coins then they are lost.